# Ionic framework Json data retrieving

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Hai I am new to ionic framework and now I get frustrated to implemented get data from the dummy Json . If anybody know about that help me.

Comment: its really simple. see the answer below. Do mark it correct if it helps you get what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its really simple. If content.js is your external file and located on the root. You get it as follows. I have embedded working plunker, play with it.

```
$http.get('content.js').success(function(response) {
     //whereever you want to put the data
    });
```

Here is the working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/hC3iY8HUG23N7DjIS2hP?p=preview